# Type-Conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, type-conversion, integer

**Theoretical  question**

I'm trying to find new practical ways to convert integers into strings and the other way around.
I only know the `.to_s` ; `.to_i` ; `.to_f` methods and would like to know if there are other ways to do to it without writing `+` to put together the variables. For example:

```
var1 = 16

puts 'I\'m ' + var1.to_s + ' years old.'
```

In longer codes is getting tiring writing all this to just convert a integer to a string.

By the way I also found this *Timer* program here on Stack and the `#{` is an example of what I'm trying to do. Adding an integer to a string without `+` and `.to_s` But I don't know how it works.

```
30.downto(0) do |i|
  puts "00:00:#{'%02d' % i}"
  sleep 1
end
```

Thank you in advance for the suggestions!

Comment: The documentation for [string literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) is worth reading. It explains escape sequences, interpolation, the difference between `'...'` and `"..."`, introduces `%q(...)` and `%Q(...)` and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has a pretty powerful string interpolator feature using `#{...}` where that can contain fairly arbitrary Ruby code. The end result is always converted to a string using, effectively, `to_s`.

That is you can do this:

```
puts "00:00:#{'%02d' % i}"
```

Where that gets stringified and then interpolated.

This is roughly the same as:

```
i_str = '%02d' % i
puts "00:00:#{i_str}"
```

Where that is effectively:

```
i_str = '%02d' % i
puts "00:00:%s" % i_str
```

You could also combine that into a single operation:

```
puts "00:00:%02d" % i
```

Where you generally use interpolation *or* `sprintf`-style template strings, not both at the same time. It keeps your code cleaner since only one mechanism is in play.

The only reason `.to_s` is needed when doing concatenation is Ruby is very particular about "adding" together two things. `x + y` has a completely different outcome depending on what `x` and `y` are.

Consider:

```
# Integer + Integer (Integer#+)
1 + 2
# => 3

# Array + Array (Array#+)
[ 1 ] + [ 2 ]
# => [1,2]

# String + String (String#+)
"1" + "2"
# => "12"
```

Note that in each case it's actually a different method being called, and the general form of `x + y` is:

```
x.send(:+, y)
```

So it's actually a method call, and as such, each method may impose restrictions on what it can operate on by emitting exceptions if it can't or won't deal.

Comment: Ohh, so the `'%02d'` has nothing to do with the _string interpolation_

Comment: To be technical, that's a *form* of interpolation, in effect, but not using the `#{...}` *string interpolation mechanism*. Ruby, like C, Python, Perl and others, supports`printf` notation for strings when using the [`String#%` method](https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/string#method-i-25). What it does is gives you more control over how that value is interpolated in terms of a template. The `#{...}` method requires you to do all the formatting yourself.

Comment: But the only thing I'm missing is what the `d` stands for?

Comment: If you follow that documentation link it links through to the [full table of placeholders](https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/kernel#method-i-sprintf) where `d` represents "argument as a decimal number".

Comment: Additionally we could coerce a String/Integer combo e.g. `class String;def coerce(other); [other.to_s,self];end;end` then `1 + "s" #=> "1s"`(explicit coercion)  alternatively `class Integer; alias_method :to_str, :to_s;end` then `"s" + 1 #=> "s1"` (implicit coercion)

Answer (score 2):

It's called *string interpolation*. For example:

```
puts "I\'m #{var1} years old."
```

The way it works is this:

1. You have to enclose the string in double quotes, not single quotes.
2. You put your variable inside this: `#{}`, e.g. `"#{variable}`".

This will always convert non-string variables into strings, and plug (i.e. interpolate) them into the surrounding string.

Comment: So the double quotes are important, I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to escape the single quote when using doubles quotes. (makes the string easier to read)

Comment: @Stefan Right, you can use single quotes inside double quotes, and also double quotes inside single quotes, without escaping them.